# Resize Form On Windows 8 Tablet When Virtual Keyboard Closes

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-8.1, tablet

I have a niggling issue  I can't resolve. I have an app which runs on a Windows 8 tablet. When the main form loads it is maximised but if the virtual keyboard is open the app only loads in the visible desktop above the keyboard.

But when the keyboard closes the main app doesn't resize to the full desktop, other apps like Word and Notepad do.

How can I detect when it has closed and resize my form accordingly?

Many thanks

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem on laptop, does the problem exists in PC/Laptop too?

Comment: It does on a PC if using the onscreen keyboard (TabTip) with it maximised. Other windows (my VS2012) resized accordingly when it opened.

Strangely on a Windows 10 tablet the form just loads at full desktop size behind the keyboard